# Set Current Date at default value in a data set?

Tags: c#, dataset, literals

I have a dataset that i am trying to set the default value as the current date and time. I believe that value needs to be a literal. Is there a certain way to do this? Because I am not able to do this using System.DateTime it seems.Any advice would be a great deal of help.

Comment: I agree with above. It is very straightforward to set a the current date and time into a Literal. Please show us what you are doing.

Comment: sorry i was trying to set it in the properties section of the xsd file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set the default value of relevant column as

```
dataTable1.Columns["dateTimeColumn"].DefaultValue = System.DateTime.Now;
```

If you fetch data from a SQL Server database, then you can set the default value using the `GETDATE` function:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_MyColumn
DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR MyColumn
```

Using this code:

```
UploadHistory.Columns["FileUploadDate"].DefaultValue = System.DateTime.Now;
```

When the table is written out as `XML`:

```
<xs:element name="FileUploadDate" 
            type="xs:dateTime" 
            default="2017-03-13T11:39:26.7980069-05:00" 
            minOccurs="0" />
```

Comment: I am trying to resolve this myself and tried your suggestion. Does not work. It sets the default value to the datetime value when the process runs.