# How to fill in Default Values in C# Dataset

Tags: c#, oracle, dataset

We are converting a legacy system with an Oracle backend to .NET C#.  I have a form with a dataset, bindingsource, tableadapter etc.  And when inserting a row via a datagridview, I am getting errors on columns not allowing null values.  (System.Data.NoNullAllowedException)  In our legacy program with it's oracle driver, when it would do an insert, the driver would fill any columns that were flagged Not Null with the default value set up in the Oracle Database if the user didn't fill it in.

Trying to find out if there is a build in option I am missing, or if I have to build this functionality.  And if I have to build it, where are good resources to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something on the lines of:

```
dataTable.Columns["ColumnName"].DefaultValue = "Default Value of Type in DB";
```

Adapted from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11022071/4282901

P.S: Though the reference is an example for SQL Server the C# code is what you need for your purpose.