# How do I automate a date to be inserted into a datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**[This is solved, i have added the answer at the bottom]**

**[Original Question]**
How do I automate adding a date to be inserted into a datagridview?

The datagridview is not binded or sourced to any SQL server as anything that user will write into the DataGridView will then be extracted and converted into a pdf table. However the dates inside the DataGridView is to be fixed with a value of today's date.

[image: DataGridView Picture]

My end result should be as per picture below :

[image]

I tried using code below to automate adding dates into new rows but it didnt work.

```
dt.Rows.Add("CurrentDate",System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
```

Note - i did add a datatable.

I also changed the method from CellContentClick to CellContentDoubleClick.

**Edit 1 :**

I updated the DGV as apparently i still require a  datatable to assign as a source to make this work.

Here's my code :

```
pretable = new DataTable();
            pretable.Columns.Add("NO", typeof(int));
            pretable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            pretable.Columns.Add("LO", typeof(string));
            pretable.Columns.Add("QT", typeof(string));
            pretable.Columns.Add("DA", typeof(DateTime));
            pretable.Columns["DA"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now;
            pretable.Columns.Add("ER", typeof(string));
            pretable.Columns.Add("RE", typeof(string));
            DataRow row = pretable.NewRow();
            row["DA"] = DateTime.Now;
            pretable.Rows.Add(row);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = pretable;
            dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells["DACL"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

DA = Date Column in DataTable

DACL = the name of the Date Column in DGV

However , my results added only an empty row as per picture below.
[image]

.

.

**[ANSWER]**

Previously on Form_Load, i added a DataTable, however i found out that this DataTable does not need to be bounded to the DGV as a Source for the date to work.

so instead on Form_Load i added this code

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["DACL"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["NOCL"].Value = totalRowsN;
```

This will work as my first Row Numbering and Date insertion.

**Thanks to ZedLepplin below for providing the base answer.**

I found out that DataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick takes way too much click for the event to happen so instead i did DataGridView1_CellClick where insertion now takes less effort.

The code i used is :

```
private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            totalRowsC = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1;
            totalRowsN = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            dataGridView1.Rows[totalRowsC].Cells["DACL"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            dataGridView1.Rows[totalRowsC].Cells["NOCL"].Value = totalRowsN;
        }
```

What this does is that TotalRowsC will be the value of Index for the code

```
dataGridView.Rows[Index].Cells[ColumnName]
```

So that it fits programming index. Programming indexes starts with 0 even though the row we see is 1. If i do not minus one in TotalRowsC , an error will prompt stating that we need to insert a value that fits the existing index.

Problem solved for Date automation.
Thank you everyone for the assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Current Date at default value in a data set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021832/set-current-date-at-default-value-in-a-data-set)

Comment: What is the purpose of the datatable and does it really have only 1 column? I suggest you make the date column in the dgv readonly and set the content when adding a new row.

Comment: @Filburt - Let me check on this.

Comment: @TaW - Ok i see what you mean by only 1 column. I have to make my datatable column to have the same number of columns as the DGV then only i can write to the DGV based on which column. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, well, I'm confused. Didn't you write that the DGV is __not__ data bound?

Comment: Yes sir. Its not data bound. But i only need the dates to be automated on DoubleClicking the content.  What i did here is 1 DataTable to fill in the Dates , and then whatever is written on all other columns inclusive of the date column will then be written to another DataTable that will be converted into a pdf form.

Comment: try `dt.Rows.Add("CurrentDate",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));`

Comment: @Filburt apparently no , thank you for the input. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a date to a column the row you want to add the date to must already exist.

So assuming the row exists and the date column is a text column then this just worked for me: -

```
yourDgvName.Rows[0].Cells["yourColumnName"].Value = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
```

Replace yourDgvName with the name of your DataGridView control.

Replace yourColumnName withe the name of your date column, or just use an index number instead of a string column name.

This will add today's date to the date column in the first row of your DataGridView control.

Alternatively, your could create a DataGridView row, add today's date to that row data and then add the row to the DataGridView control.

Comment: Here's how i do in Form_Load

```
pretable = new DataTable();
            pretable.Columns.Add("DA", typeof(DateTime));
            pretable.Columns["DA"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now;
            DataRow row = pretable.NewRow();
            row["DA"] = DateTime.Now;
            pretable.Rows.Add(row);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = pretable;
            dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells["DACL"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: seems doesnt work to comment here. let me add in my question

Comment: I have edited my questions to reflect the changes. Added an image to better representation of problem

Comment: I am confused about the reference to CellContentDoubleClick. Do you want the date added when you add data into the data table, or should the data appear when something is double clicked?

Comment: Now I am even more confused, I tried your code and it worked for me. However I suspect I know why. I did not edit the DataGridView control when I added it to my form, I just added a completely empty DataGridViewControl.

Comment: My mistake was that a column index starts from 0 , i mistakenly put 5 instead of 4 as i started my column index number by 1.

Comment: Now im trying to add the code to "CellContentDoubleClick" method, so that all the new date rows will have dates upon double clicking.

Comment: Great , now i have everything under control. Thank you for this!

Comment: i added your answer to my post to clear for others and marked it as an answer provided by you. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks. My pleasure.